# Hibernate Eager loading (many to one) ,Jersey Rest to produce JSON

Tags: hibernate, jersey

This is long one.
I am developing Restful Web Services to produce JSON data using jersey ,Hibernate and database is MySQL.
I have been using Hibernate and been doing all native-sql in my project to communicate to database.

I have 2 schema in database and have respective entity classes,

**Schema 1**

Tables:Jobs,Events,Clubs,Entries

1. Jobs ----- 1 to many--->
2. Events Jobs ----- 1 to many---> Clubs
3. Events ----- 1 to many ---> Entries
4. Clubs---------->Entries   (one to many)

**Schema 2**

Tables: Jobs, Events,Clubs,Races,Results,Splits

1. Jobs ---->Events ,Clubs (one to many)
2. Events------>Races      (one to many)
3. Races ------> Results   (one to many)
4. Clubs---------->Entries (one to many)
5. Results------>Splits      (one to many) Also has eagerly mapped

All tables in Schema 2 have key which matches to Schema 1 tables , For eg:
Schema 2 Jobs has schema1.job_id , Schema 2 events has schema 1.event_id  key .
To be simple we can access data from Schema_2/Schema_1 tables using Schema_1/Schema_2 table keys

I have all endpoints which return data from both database. I been doing cross schema queries. And doing good so far with out major trouble. But I have been struck with this issue.

I have to get results data (also splits data which is eagerly mapped)  from Results, Splits tables from Schema 2 along with event,clubs,entries info from Schema 1 as well. I am unable to achieve this.

**Results.java (Entity)**

```
  @XmlRootElement
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "results", catalog = "schema2")
  public class Results implements java.io.Serializable {

private BigDecimal id;
private Set<Splits> splits = new HashSet<Splits>(0);
/* some more fields*/

//getters and setters

    @XmlID
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IDAdapter.class)
    @JsonProperty("resultId")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 6)
    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return this.id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="result", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Splits> getSplits() {
        return splits;
    }

    public void setSplits(Set<Splits> splits) {
        this.splits = splits;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Splits.java (Entity class)**

```
private BigDecimal id;
private Results result;

   // Property accessors
@Id
@Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 6)
public BigDecimal getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@JsonIgnore
@XmlIDREF
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="Pid",nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
public Results getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(Results result) {
    this.result = result;
```

In my Dao, I been doing native sql queries using Hibernate

```
 String sql=   "SELECT c1.organization, group_concat(c1.short_name separator     '/'),e1.event_description, res2.* FROM Schema_2.results res2 
    left outer join Schema_2.splits s2 on (s2.pid=res2.id)  
    left outer join Schema_2.races ra2 on(res2.pid=ra2.id) 
    join Schema_2.events e2 on(ra2.pid=e2.id) 
    left outer join Schema_2.entries en2 on (res2.entrypid=en2.id) 
    left outer join Schema_2.clubs c2 on(en2.pid=c2.id) 
    left outer join Schema_1.clubs c1 on (c1.org_id=c2.regOrgId)  
    left outer join Schema_1.events e1 on (e1.event_id=e2.regeventId)
    where res2.rmrsid=:jobId and en.entryStatus='Entered' 
    and e2.regEventId=:eventId group by en2.entryId order by res2.finishPlace";
            Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql)
    .addEntity("res2",Schema_2.Results.class)
    .addEntity("c1" ,Schema_1.Clubs.class)
    .addEntity("e1",Schema_1.Events.class)
    .setParameter("jobId", jobId).setParameter("eventId", eventId);

              resultList=query.list();
              tx.commit();
```

What I am expecting  in my Json feed is :

```
{ "success":true, "count":some number,"msg":"","data":[ "organization":"ABC","eventDescription":"Event 1", **"resultNo":1,"resultTime":"8:30","ResultFinishTime":"xxxxx","splits":[{splits1 data},{splits2 data},{ splits 3 data}..]** ]}
```

But I am running into error:

java.sql.SQLException: column  not found

When I only select res2.* with the same query and addEntity("res2",Schema_2.Results.class)

I have no issues and getting data from Results as well as eagerly loaded splits data like this

```
{ "success":true, "count":some number,"msg":"","data":[**"resultNo":1,"resultTime":"8:30","ResultFinishTime":"xxxxx","splits":[{splits1 data},{splits2 data},{ splits 3 data}..]** ]}
```

Does any one have encountered similar situation, Is there any work around for this.

P.S

When used Transformer , EntityToBean or EntityToMap, child collections(Splits) are included in my data set, I get all data but except splits data.

Thank you in advance.